# Error in reading json using aws-python-sdk

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-iot

I am registering thing using [register_thing](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iot.html#IoT.Client.register_thing) sdk command and passing my CSR as parameters:

```
f = open("template.json", "r")
    print(f.read())
    template = json.dumps(f.read())
    #template1 = f.read()
    f.close()
    response = client.register_thing(templateBody=template, parameters={"ThingName": thing_name,
                                                                        "CSR": csr.decode('UTF-8')
                                                                    })
```

But I am getting error in reading json:

[image]

I checked my json file and found no problem:

```
{
    "Parameters" : {
       "ThingName" : {
         "Type" : "String"
       },
       "SerialNumber" : {
         "Type" : "String"
       },
       "Location" : {
          "Type" : "String",
          "Default" : "WA"
       },
       "CSR" : {
         "Type" : "String"
       }
    },
    "Resources" : {
      "thing" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::IoT::Thing",
        "Properties" : {
          "ThingName" : {"Ref" : "ThingName"},
          "AttributePayload" : { "version" : "v1", "serialNumber" :  {"Ref" : "SerialNumber"}}
        }
      },
      "certificate" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::IoT::Certificate",
        "Properties" : {
          "CertificateSigningRequest": {"Ref" : "CSR"},
          "Status" : "ACTIVE"
        }
      },
      "policy" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::IoT::Policy",
        "Properties" : {
          "PolicyDocument": "{\"Version\": \"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\": [{\"Effect\": \"Allow\",\"Action\": [\"iot:*\"],\"Resource\": [\"*\"]}]}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Can someone give me hint what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Check your template is saved well. I think the `json.dumps` is not giving the correct result. Let us change the code as follows:

```
import json

with open("test.json", "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()

template = json.dumps(contents)
```

which will give you the correct template.

Comment: what is the difference between your code and mine? in both cases `json.dumps` is used after reading the file.

Anyways, I used your code and now it can read my json file but i am getting other error:
`An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the RegisterThing operation: Invalid registration template. Template format error: unsupported type or structure with location of [Source: (String)""{\n    \"Parameters\" : {\n       \"ThingName\" : {\n         \"Type\" : \"String\"\n       },\n       \"SerialNumber\" : {\n truncated 669 chars]; line: 1, column: 1]`